# Can anyone give me some android accelerometer example code?

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am developing a application which needs a new acceleration datum every 10 millisecond. And i need to save the data into a files. Can anyone give me some android accelerometer example codes as reference? Thanks very much.

Comment: you should post your effort before asking for source code

Comment: you should have googled out first

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the SensorManager to learn how to get accelerometer data:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

You can access the SensorManager straight from your application context.

```
SensorManager manager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SensorManager);
```

Then you register a SensorEventListener, the sensor you want to listen to, and the rate. The SensorManager class provides constants for the refresh rate. For your purposes, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME might be fast enough, but I feel like SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST is a safer bet. To my knowledge, there's no hard numbers on the rates of the defaults, so just see what works best.

```
Sensor accel = manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
manager.registerListener(new MySensorEventListener(), accel, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

Then, every time a new event is polled from the accelerometer, it will call the listener's onSensorChanged method:

```
public class MySensorEventListener implements SensorEventListener {
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // do what you need to do with the data from event
    }
}
```